# What does Mt mean?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

When looking at my Hero's skills, the primary attack skill has a stat of "Mt". What does this mean? It looks like it's pretty low, most of the time under 10.

Comment: Just a heads up it means the same as all the other fire emblem games, in case you play any of those :)

Comment: @hammythepig I've never played any fire emblem before this mobile game :D

Comment: I must recommend them! Great games!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mt is a Fire Emblem abbreviation for "Might".
It's essentially the weapon's strength stat. Add the wielder's attack to it and you have raw damage.

Comment: Small clarification: In Fire Emblem Heroes, the weapon's Might is already added to the character's Attack. If you're trying to determine a character's IV, you actually need to *subtract* the weapon's Might from the character's Attack.